# differentiate between two events

Tags: javascript, html

I have two different `<span>` elements which both call the same function, `changeSubHeader` when clicked. How can I determine *which* span was clicked?

Here is my code:

```
<span onclick="changeSubHeader(this)" class='dif'>difficult</span>
<span onclick="changeSubHeader(this)" class='easy'>easy</span>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Comment: Also, show how you assign the click events to the spans

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen - even before my edit the question was very clear. @NicoHaase the question is, quite obviously, how to determine the specific `<span>` that was clicked from within the `changeSubHeader` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element's [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className):

```js
var a = {
  'dif': 'First span element',
  'easy': 'Second span element'
}

function changeSubHeader(t) {
  console.log(a[t.className]);
}
```

```css
span{
  text-decoration:underline;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
Do the <span onclick="changeSubHeader(this)" class='dif'>difficult</span> things while
they are <span onclick="changeSubHeader(this)" class='easy'>easy</span> and do the
great things while they are small.
```

Comment: It's unclear why this was downvoted, it seems perfectly reasonable, if marginally over-complicated to address there immediate question.

Comment: @igalbar No problem :). If it solves your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)